# What is a valid "letter" for named ranges in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

According to the Excel documentation: [Learn about syntax rules for names](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64#bmsyntax_rules_for_names):

> **Valid characters**    The first character of a name must be a letter, an
>   underscore character (_), or a backslash (). Remaining characters in
>   the name can be **letters**, numbers, periods, and underscore characters.

But what exactly is a letter?
I thought this means only ASCII letters, like: A-Z and a-z
But obviously I am wrong, because also the following work (on my English Excel 2013):

- German umlauts: Ö,ö,Ü,ü, etc.
- French accents: é, ê, etc.

So how can I check in VBA which characters in a string are valid and which are not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the answer to the question is quite complex. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41877926/1041641) from user 
[Gary's Student](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2474656/garys-student) is already quite close, but here are more things to consider:

- single-character names:
  Examples:

  - "a" is allowed
  - "c" is not allowed
- characters at the start:
  Examples:

  - "cX" is allowed
  - "?X" is not allowed
- characters after the start
  Examples:

  - "_?" is allowed ("?", "?_" are not)
- combinations:

  - "R1048576C1" invalid
  - "R1048577C1" valid
  - "\xx" valid
  - "\x" invalid
- unicode
- Workbook names vs. Worksheet names:
  e.g. "\a" is allowed on the Worksheet, but not on the Workbook

I've made a [GitHub project excel-names](https://github.com/MartinTrummer/excel-names/) which includes an Excel Sheet with a list of valid characters (also unicode) and some VBA code that you can use.

Moreover, the project includes functions that consider the full Excel Name (not only single characters): read [the documentation](https://github.com/MartinTrummer/excel-names/blob/master/VbaCode.md#excel-name-rules) for full details

Comment: nice Martin! I think you still miss one :) the names that starts with "_xl", which are reserved for Excel internal usage, I have several names like that (whose Visible property is set to False) but it might depend of the formulas used in the wb/ws: `_xlfn._xlws.FILTER, _xlfn.COUNTIFS, _xlfn.FORMULATEXT, _xlfn.IFERROR, _xlfn.IFS, _xlfn.SUMIFS, _xlfn.UNIQUE`

Answer (score 5):

I ran this tiny bit of code:

```
Sub WhatsInAName()
    Dim i As Long, CH As String, r As Range, msg As String
    Dim K As Long
    Set r = Range("A1")
    On Error Resume Next
    K = 1

    For i = 1 To 255
        CH = Chr(i)
        r.Name = CH
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Cells(K, 1) = i
            K = K + 1
        Else
            Err.Number = 0
        End If
    Next i

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

which should record the ascii codes for valid **name starters**.  I got this:

65
66
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
92
95
97
98
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112
113
115
116
117
118
119
120
121
122
131
133
134
135
137
138
140
142
145
146
147
148
150
151
153
154
156
158
159
161
164
167
168
170
173
175
176
177
178
179
180
181
182
183
184
185
186
188
189
190
191
192
193
194
195
196
197
198
199
200
201
202
203
204
205
206
207
208
209
210
211
212
213
214
215
216
217
218
219
220
221
222
223
224
225
226
227
228
229
230
231
232
233
234
235
236
237
238
239
240
241
242
243
244
245
246
247
248
249
250
251
252
253
254
255

<strike>I have no idea why ***67*** is missing.</strike>

**EDIT#5:**

Here is a list of the valid characters **after the first character**:

32
46
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
63
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
92
95
97
98
99
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
110
111
112
113
114
115
116
117
118
119
120
121
122
128
131
133
134
135
136
137
138
140
142
145
146
147
148
150
151
152
153
154
156
158
159
161
164
167
168
170
173
175
176
177
178
179
180
181
182
183
184
185
186
188
189
190
191
192
193
194
195
196
197
198
199
200
201
202
203
204
205
206
207
208
209
210
211
212
213
214
215
216
217
218
219
220
221
222
223
224
225
226
227
228
229
230
231
232
233
234
235
236
237
238
239
240
241
242
243
244
245
246
247
248
249
250
251
252
253
254
255

Thanks to Martin Trummer.

Comment: 67 is missing, because "c" is not valid for the first character (starting characters have even stricter rules). so your test should maybe use an underscore for the first character of your test-name.

Comment: @MartinTrummer  You are correct! ..........The list correctly omits both **C** and **R**

Comment: Nice (+1) although I wonder if even more is possible if you bring Unicode into play.

Comment: Of course -- using `ChrW` with a larger for loop range is the way to go. The answer might depend on which version of Excel the test is run in.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and I might be a litle off topic but I have just ran into a problem whit Excel named ranges.

I was trying to use names like CP01 , CP02, ... and, well, excel keeps telling that those were invalid names although no invalid characters were in the name.

Adding an underscore solves the problem. Names like CP01_ or CP_01 works just fine.

So there is resctriction with valid characters *and*, as has already been refered, there are also restrictions with the combination of the characters.

I haven't been throug the bottom of the question but, besides the previousily refered combinations of characters, it's not also possible to use any combination of characters that can be interperted as cell adress in A1 notation.